# Help identifying an old bayonet

Tags: identification, weapons

I was helping my parents move into a new place recently and my dad and I came across this old bayonet that my grandfather had given to my dad. My dad doesn't know anything of its history, so I'm hoping someone here can help out.

It's definitely a bayonet, it has a track cut into the bottom of the handle for attaching to a lug on the barrel of a rifle, and the rear of the guard is rounded for sitting against the barrel.

There's also what appears to be a maker's mark on the base of the blade, just above the guard.

I'm interested to know if this bayonet was commonly used in either of the world wars, or if it has any other interesting history behind it. I'm also curious if anyone can identify the maker's mark on the blade as well.

[image: Picture of the bayonet]
[image: Picture of the makers mark]

Comment: Which country are you in? Do you have measurements for the bayonet?

Comment: @SteveBird I'm in the United States. I don't have a precise measurement, but knowing the handle is about 4 inches, I took some pixel measurements and calculated the blade length to be about 25-28 inches.

Comment: Any ideas on where your grandfather may have acquired such a thing? Did he perhaps serve in WWI, WWII, Korea, or Vietnam?

Comment: @T.E.D. He did serve in the military, some time in the 1930's to 1940's, my dad would probably know more, I'll have to ask him when I have a chance.

Comment: The evidence would seem to suggest that he served in or around WWII, somewhere in the Pacific. Hard to imagine where _else_ he would have found a broken Japanese bayonet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A little googling and matching the makers marks indicates that this is a Japanese bayonet, known as a [Type 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_30_bayonet)

> Some 8.4 million were produced, and it remained in front-line use from
> the Russo-Japanese War to the end of World War II. All Japanese
> infantrymen were issued with the Type 30, whether they were armed with
> a rifle or pistol, or even if they were unarmed. Because of its
> reliability, it was a valuable tool for the Japanese army.

---

Someone asked about a similar weapon on a forum [here](https://www.theakforum.net/threads/bayonet-identification.211914/) where a user posted a sheet showing the [makers marks](https://www.theakforum.net/threads/bayonet-identification.211914/#lg=attachment_xfUid-1-1691360036&slide=0). This includes one matching yours indicating origin at the *Toyada Jido Shokki Seisakusho Arsenal* or the [Toyoda Automatic Loom works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakichi_Toyoda#Toyoda_Automatic_Loom_Works).

[image]

---

Here is an image of one from the [Australian war Museum](https://www.awm.gov.au/collection/C1074671)

[image]

(You can see yours seems to have part broken off the top.)

Comment: So it's an old Toyota (yes, basically the same company)